# sql - order by for each group

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT
    USER .id,
    listing.country,
    count(listing.id) AS count
FROM    USER
INNER JOIN listing ON USER.id = listing.user_id
GROUP BY listing.country,   USER.id
ORDER BY count DESC;
```

and the result i get looks like this:

[image]

however i'd like it to be grouped by country so that the users can be ranked per country by their number of listings. is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the result set you're looking to get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have multiple `ORDER BY` columns:

```
SELECT user.id, 
       listing.country,
       count(listing.id) as count 
FROM user
INNER JOIN listing ON (user.id = listing.user_id) 
GROUP BY listing.country, user.id 
ORDER BY country, count DESC;
```